# Does parallel mergesort run differently on mesh vs linear array of processors?

Tags: algorithms, parallelism, parallel-programming

I'm currently taking course on introduction to algorithm and I came across the parallel mergesort algorithm. 
My question is: Is there any differences in the algorithm plan if it runs on a 2d mesh instead of infinite linear proccessors ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Please define the terms `mesh` and `linear array of processors`, and/or provide online references to such definitions.

---

There are different flavors of mergesort algorithms. One remarkable difference is:

- For merging two sorted halves of size `N/2` arrays into a fully sorted `N` array, does it take exactly one stage (performing exactly `N` or `O(N)` comparisons), or does it take multiple stages, most commonly `O(log(N))` as many stages (for a total number of `O(N*log(N))` comparisons)?

---

- The single-threaded mergesort, the one typically taught in the introduction to programming classes, relies on **scanning** the two halves, "dequeuing" the smaller value of the two front values out of the two halves. This takes exactly `N-1` comparisons. Because it is sequential, it takes `O(N)` time steps.

---

- The parallel mergesort, which is most likely a parallel bitonic mergesort, such as

  - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter
  - http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~tvrdik/17/html/Section17.html
  - Requires `log(N)` stages;
  - Inside each stage, `O(N)` comparisons are performed - one comparison per processing element - and all processing elements do this simultaneously.
  - Therefore, it requires `O(log(N))` time, despite having performed vastly many more total number of comparisons of `N*log(N)`

---

**There are other flavors of parallelized merge sort. I can't answer them unless you clarify what flavor of merge sort you're learning.**